# Civicrm Unrecognized option in recordGeneratedLetters

Tags: pdf, printing

I was trying to print Thank-you letters. But I am getting the below error. Civicrm version is 5.8.1. Any help to fix the issue is appreciated.

> "Civicrm Unrecognized option in recordGeneratedLetters."

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it myself. Navigated to Administer->System Settings->Misc & set "Record generated letters" to "Do not record" from the drop-down.